# lwc-webpack + storybook

Tags: lightning-web-components

Have a requirement to set up Storybook for lightning web components

lwc-webpack-plugin is at 2.1.0

Got the following /storybook/main.js file, which works up until there is a need to compile css files.

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials"
  ],

  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new LwcWebpackPlugin({
        modules: [
          { dir: 'src/modules' },
          { npm: 'lightning-base-components' }
        ],
    })
    );
    return config;
  },
}
```

Getting an error as following

```
time.css Unknown word

  1 | function stylesheet(useActualHostSelector, token) {
> 2 |   var shadowSelector = token ? ("[" + token + "]") : "";
    |       ^
  3 |   var hostSelector = token ? ("[" + token + "-host]") : "";
  4 |   return [".someCustomClass", shadowSelector, " {background-color: red;}"].join('');

    at node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
    at node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.loader (node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:102:7)
```

Suspecting it has to do with reconciling storybook with LwcWebpackPlugin - specifically processing of css files.

Would appreciate any advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested - the solution is to leave lwc compiling to lwc-webpack

Specifically, exclude any folder containing lwc i.e. "src/modules" or "node_modules/lightning-base-components" from getting processed by the default Storybook's webpack config.

The config would look like something in the lines of  -

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
    exclude: [/node_modules/, /src/modules/]
}
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, could you go into a bit more detail as to how you were able to solve it?